# Can't install SimPy

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, simpy

I may be doing this incorrectly, if so please let me know.
I'm trying to install SimPy using Navigator 1.6.2. I click Environments, then to the left of Channels, I select ALL, then search for SimPy.  It does not appear. Yet when I look at Anaconda cloud there are several versions available (for win-64).
Am operating on a work PC, have previously been able to install packages. Have not contacted IT support yet as they are telephone only, and Python is unsupported, so I need to make sure I have exhausted options before I approach them.
Because of the difficulties here I uninstalled and reinstalled Ananconda, most of what follows was attempted after the reinstall.

I've also tried:
installed Miniconda 3 and tried installing using the command line

```
  conda install -c asmeurer simpy
```

which at first results in a ProxyError (MaxRetryError ..... Cannot connect to proxy ... tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required
Then based on this advice I tried:

```
set NO_PROXY=continuum.io,anaconda.org
```

after which the proxy problem seems to be bypassed but now I receive an error "CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for URL https://conda.anaconda.org/asmeurer/win-64/repodata.json followed by "Max retries exceeded."

Also tried to download and install from the local file:

```
 conda install --offline C:\simpy-3.0.10.tar.gz
```

which results in PackageNotFoundError: package missing in current win-64 channels (same result with taret C:\simpy-3.0.10.tar)

Also tried pip:

```
pip install -U simpy
```

which results in several attempts which all "Failed to establish new connection"

And:

```
python C:\simpy\setup.py install
```

starts to install but aborts because it "cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref' whilst executing weakref.py:

```
from _weakref import (
     getweakrefcount,
     getweakrefs,
     ref,
     proxy,
     CallableProxyType,
     ProxyType,
     ReferenceType,
     _remove_dead_weakref)
```

the import appears to be from a package "_weakref", which as far as I can tell means it is a C-coded module, 
\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\jedi\evaluate\compiled\fake\_weakref.pym:

```
def proxy(object, callback=None):
    return object

class ref():
    def __init__(self, object, callback=None):
        self.__object = object

    def __call__(self):
        return self.__object
```

To me, it looks like this is missing a whole bunch of procedures that weakref is trying to call.

Any suggestions how to install SimPy from here?  Time to break down and try to explain to corporate IT?

Comment: what is the -U for in PIP install?

Comment: Apparently it means Upgrade, will allow overwriting of any previous versions that may be installed.

Comment: We did not package SimPy for conda. You can only install it via pip.

Comment: or [contribute](https://conda-forge.github.io/#contribute) the recipe to conda-forge

Comment: Do you use a `.condarc`? If so, please post its content.

Answer (score 1):

It might be causing due to network error. Reboot the computer, check your internet connection and try `pip install simpy`. Installation works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Install it on the jupyter notebook:

[image]